# Differing debugger-pointeraddress between baseclass and derived class

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers

Given, that class B is the baseclass and class D is derived from B.
Using the the VS-Debugger - if you have a pointer to an instance of class D - which by our definition is also a pointer to class B, so you can cast it - these pointers are shown to be slightly different?

```
# pseudo-code:
B *pB = new D();
D *pD = (D*) pB;
# why is: pb != pD
```

Comment: if `D : [A,]B[,C]` need use `static_cast` but not `reinterpret_cast`. if `B` not first base in `D` or `D` have virtual functions and `B` have not - `pD` will be != `pB`

Comment: so if you do `(void*)pB == (void*)pD` compare (binary pointer compare) result will be `TRUE`, but when you compare `pB==pD` compiler **cast** `pD` to `B*` first. and again if `B` not first base of `D` or `D` have virtual functions and `B` have not - result will be different. so or do `pD=static_cast<D*>(pB)` or compare `(void*)pB==(void*)pD` or `pB==(B*)pD`

Comment: You can EXTEND the vtable in the derived class without getting a second vtable, but yes, if you inherit from more than one base then you may get two vtables. Adding a vtable in the middle of an inheritance chain will also have that effect.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - *You can EXTEND the vtable in the derived class* - only if `B` also have vtable. but in case `B` have not vatable at all, and `D` have it - already `B` will be placed not at begin of `D`

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, exactly what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called aliasing.
D *pD = (D*) pB;
Here you are assigning pd to pb, no matter if you are casting it. You are not creating a new object. The addresses would be same, the object at the location has changed the location is still the same.

Imagine it as constructing a new home at you current address, your address will still remain the same.
So if you compare both these pointers, they would be pointing to the same address.

Comment: "The addresses would be same"? OP writes this is not the case! It depends on inheritance and existence of virtual methods in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is standard mandates this. Only getting same value when casting forth and back between a base class pointer and a derived class one is required:

```
B *pB = new D();
D *pD = (D*) pB;
B *pB2 = (B*) pD;
// pB2 == pB is guaranteed per C++ standard
// but nothing is required between pB and pD
```

Implementations often use different pointer addresses for a derived class pointer and a base class one as soon as virtual methods and their associated vTable are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard doesn't say they should the same.

The main motivation is obviously multiple inheritance. A class can derive from multiple base classes, so obviously you can't impose that the start of the derived subobject be the same as the start of the base class, as there could be more than 1 base classes.